# Java - Question on Free Physical Memory and JVM memory

Tags: java, operating-system, jmx

Using `OperatingSystemMXBean` I manage to print out the following for my application:

`JVM Memory: Free: 6461 MB; Total: 7000 MB; Max: 7000 MB;;; CommittedVirtualMemory: 13920 MB
FreePhysicalMemory: 372 MB; TotalPhysicalMemory: 10239 MB;; FreeSwapSpace: 339 MB; TotalSwapSpace: 14997 MB`

What is strange is that `FreePhysicalMemory` i.e. `getFreePhysicalMemorySize()` method shows something really strange, how can this be so low when `Runtime` is reporting that almost the entire JVM is free?

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#freeMemory--

The above shows what's the JVM memory usage is. So, does it mean `getFreePhysicalMemorySize()` is not necessarily impacted by JVM usage?

Comment: You can read `FreePhysicalMemory` as `WastedPhysicalMemory`. It's not used for caches or anything useful, so it's just "extra". It has little to do with the actual available memory.

Comment: @Kayaman        but it seems that committedVirtualMemory - FreePhysicalMemory
almost equals to total JVM memory. Does this mean the RAM is not sufficient.

Comment: Of course not. You're not using `Runtime` and `OperatingSystemMXBean` to try to determine whether you have enough memory, are you?

Comment: @Kayaman        If we cannot use Runtime and OperatingSystemMXBean - then what do we use to determine JVM stats? Also, these are ingested by various JMX exporter. Are you saying these are not correct metrics ?